# How to install Kali VB image?

Tags: kali-linux

I'd like to install Kali's VirtualBox image in order of avoiding some bugs with standard iso file. When I download it I see not just one file as I expexted but various kinds of files. How can it be mounted in VirtualBox? Thanks.

Comment: This is a VirtualBox usage question and not a security question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new machine and when promoted to select the disk configurations, choose to use existing virtual disk.

[image]
[image]